# How to fix pagination after making a search for specific data in django_tables2

Tags: django, pagination, django-tables2

In my project I am using with success django_tables2 in order to achieve server side processing.

The only thing that I do not know how to handle is that after searching, for example by name in a template rendering clients for my application, the search despite the fact that gives some returned results based on the name, it is not working properly **if the result records are spread in more than one page based on my pagination.**

In other words, when I am clicking the **2** (second page of my returned results), the app is showing  all the pages concerning the clients **1 2 3 ...45 next** (as  i want to reach the /clients/ url, and not the **1 2 next** structure for only the custom search data.

**This happening also when I am clicking the next and previous buttons.**

One easy solution It could be to increase my pagination limit in order to show all the possible results in one page, but this solution is not proper for big result sets.

**Is there any solution to avoid loading and showing all the pages in the search bar and only keeping the results of my custom search?**

Below is my snippets.

```
url.py

url(r'^clients/$', views.client_list, name='client_list'),


models.py

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Surname")
activity = models.IntegerField(choices=ACTIVITY_OPTIONS, null=True,default=ACTIVE)


views.py

def client_list(request, template_name='clients/client_list.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_string = request.POST['search_client']
        current_client=Client.objects.filter(Q(activity=1) &  Q(name=search_string)| Q(surname=search_string))
        single_table=ClientTable(current_client)
        RequestConfig(request).configure(single_table)
        return render(request,template_name, {'single_table': single_table})
    else:
        clients=Client.objects.filter(activity=1)
        table = ClientTable(clients)
        RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
        return render(request,template_name, {'table': table})

tables.py

class ClientTable(tables.Table):

class Meta:
        #define the model
        model = Client
        exclude=('..')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        sequence = ("surname", "name",)


template

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load has_group %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

<form class="well" method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
Client Search:<br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search_client">
  <br>
        {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              {% bootstrap_icon "like" %} Submit
          </button>
      {% endbuttons %}
  </form>


{% if single_table %}
    {% render_table single_table %}
{% endif %}

{% if table %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endif %}


</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally after searching I found a solution.

Django filters https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html can be used in situations like this one.

The steps I followed are:

1) import the 'django_filters', to settings.py

2) Define the filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Patient


    class ClientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')


        class Meta:
            model = Client
            fields = ['id','name','surname']
```

3) Modify the views.py

```
class FilteredClientListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = ClientTable
    model = Client
    template_name ='clients/client_list2.html'

    filterset_class = ClientFilter
```

4) Modify urls.py accordingly since I used class based function

```
url(r'^clients2/$', views.FilteredClientListView.as_view(), name='client_list2'),
```

5) Modify my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load has_group %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

<form class="well" method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
Client Search:<br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search_client">
  <br>
        {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              {% bootstrap_icon "like" %} Submit
          </button>
      {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

{% if filter %}
    <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
        {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
        {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
    </form>
{% endif %}

{% if single_table %}
    {% render_table single_table %}
{% endif %}

{% if table %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endif %}


</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

P.S : importing in the views.py the appropriate tables and filters